# How to use a Case Statement to Include or Exclude Data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a check box on an HTML page that I want to use to determine what group of employees should be included or excluded from a report. So far I can only get the query to include ALL employees regardless of status if the check box is NOT checked or to show ONLY retired employees if the checkbox IS checked. ('' is the check box)

```
SELECT USERS.UserName AS "Last_Name", USERS.UserName_First AS "First_Name", 
USERS.Retired AS "Retired"
FROM   Employee USERS
WHERE   
USERS.Retired IS NULL OR USERS.Retired = '<$client.form.retired>'
ORDER BY isnull(USERS.Retired , 0)
```

The way I want this to work is if the checkbox is CHECKED to include Retired Employees along with Active employees and to order by the Retired status.
But if the check box is NOT checked I ONLY want it to show Active employees and to completely leave out Retired employees on the report- its doing the opposite of this.
(A side issue is that the column would be a random blank column but not sure I can do anything about that at all).

How do I use a Case statement to achieve this in the WHERE clause?

Comment: So, what is the problem with the query? It looks like it should work the way you want.

Comment: when the check box is checked it excludes active employee's.  it does the opposite of what I want it to do.  it should never exclude Active- only restrict Retired if the check box is checked.

Comment: If the user is not retired what value will be in field `USERS.Retired` `NULL` or `0`?

Comment: I think you need to check `'<$client.form.retired>'= 1 Or ISNULL(USER.RETIRED, 0) = 0 ` where `0` being False and `1` beign True. So in this case if Retired checbox is checked you do not filter anything and get all records, but if its not checked then you filter the values where retired is null.

Comment: @Nilesh
Not sure if anybody is still following this issue but I'm still struggling with it. How does the above statement differ from what I have?    
    USERS.Retired IS NULL OR USERS.Retired = '<$client.form.retired>'
The checkbox value is set to 1 already so it mirrors a retired users value in the DB. So Retired = 1 in DB and Active = Null in DB.

Comment: @Igor Users.Retired is 0 in the DB if they are still active and 1 if they are Retired.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT USERS.UserName AS "Last_Name", USERS.UserName_First AS "First_Name", 
USERS.Retired AS "Retired"
FROM   Employee USERS
WHERE  @Retired='True' OR ( @Retired='False' and Users.Retired IS NULL) 
ORDER BY isnull(USERS.Retired , 0)
```

Comment: I think what I'm missing is understanding how "@Retired" is recognized and associated with the check box.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the way that you are using parameters, but something like this should work:

```
SELECT USERS.UserName AS "Last_Name", USERS.UserName_First AS "First_Name", 
USERS.Retired AS "Retired"
FROM   Employee USERS
WHERE  @Retired /*your parameter from your form*/ IS NOT NULL
OR Users.Retired IS NULL 
ORDER BY isnull(USERS.Retired , 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to use case statement, add in a parameter will do

if your checkbox is checked, then there are some parameter will stored into @Retired, if is it not checked, then null value will pass into @Retired, if there are null value, sql will retrieved data back to u, cheer =)

```
SELECT USERS.UserName AS "Last_Name", USERS.UserName_First AS "First_Name", 
USERS.Retired AS "Retired"
FROM   Employee USERS
WHERE   
(@Retired IS NULL OR USERS.Retired = @Retired)
ORDER BY isnull(USERS.Retired , 0)
```

Comment: ps: i assumed users,retired is ur parameter, sorry if i guess wrong =O

Comment: hmmm I'm not familiar with using "parameters". I'll have to look that up to understand better...

Comment: I'm confused how the code above references the checkbox since it not referred to in the code?

Comment: try it, and believe yourself can make it ! this is very easy =)

Comment: so i believe you are generate a dynamic query in ur code behind, this is not suggested, however u can make a try on it

Comment: Ok giving it a try now!

Comment: if your query is in code behind, juz make it like if (Retired.Checked){ find active user) else (exclude where condition), if you are using parameter, normally we will use code to pass the variable to our sql

Comment: hmm will the issue may be that I'm embedding sql code inside of a proprietary system and has to reference different elements within the application.  It's not recognizing parameters within the application.  I even attempted setting it to reflect (@Retired IS NULL OR USERS.Retired = <$client.form.retired>) but that does not work either. within the application it has to be able to reference the merge string (i.e. <$client.form.retired>).  I'm not sure if I can incorporate parameters and variables within the application itself.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I may just have to take a different approach completely since there are other factors to the query working that is difficult to explain.

Comment: do u able to get <$client.form.retired> value? if yes then u may make a checking on that, try is your <$client.form.retired> statement correct or not =)

Answer (score 0):

Not able to post as a comment, so adding it as an answer

The above statement will first check if the User.Retired flag is null (that means Active user) and then if it finds the Active user it will never check the second condition i.e. 
    `USERS.Retired = <$client.form.retired>`

I think this will not work.

I assume what you need is, add the Retired rows to the results only if the checkbox is checked. In that case you need to first check if the checkbox was checked on the UI. If yes then dont filter the rows at all cause you need all the rows including Active.

If the checkbox is not checked the the next condition will filter the records which are Active. You just need to change the query i wrote a little bit like this

```
'<$client.form.retired>'= 1 Or ISNULL(USER.Active, 0) = 0
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your continued help. I've finally resolved the problem and it was a very simple solution but a huge problem with the DB integrity. Our test DB did not mirror the production DB in how it stored the value. Retired is not Null in the test DB but is set to 0. Prod is Null.  changing it to this solved it:
    AND ((USERS.Retired IS NULL OR USERS.Retired = 0) OR USERS.Retired = '<$client.form.retired>')

I queried the DB in prod but did not repeat this in the test site because it should have been identical. I was setting the value to 0 in my query so i didn't catch the problem.